# Counting number of digits in integer

Tags: java, arrays, int

My code is supposed to prompt the user for an integer and count the occurrences of each digit in the integer. But it outputs nothing. Please help and here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NumberCounts {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         int arr [] = new int [10];
         int num;
         int outcome;

         System.out.println(" Enter a number: "); 
         num = scan.nextInt();

         while ( num != 0){
             outcome = num % 10;
             arr[num % 10]+=1;
             num /= num;
         }

         for ( int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
             System.out.println(i + " : " + arr[i]);
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: `num /= num`?? Anything divided by itself is 1.  And 1 is never equal to 0, so your loop isn't going to exit.

Comment: I think `num /= num` should read `num /= 10`.

Comment: A debugger would find this sort of thing very quickly, if the OP would just use one.

Comment: See also [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/1553851)

Comment: Dawood this is what happened when I tried to do num/= 10;

Comment: Enter a number: 
45544
0 : 0
1 : 0
Exception in thread "main" 2 : 0
3 : 0
4 : 3
5 : 2
6 : 0
7 : 0
8 : 0
9 : 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at NumberCounts.main(NumberCounts.java:41)

Comment: Converting the int to String and processing that one could be easier I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, you are dividing `num` by itself, then assigning the result back to `num`.  This will make `num` equal to `1` forever.  Change it to

```
num /= 10;
```

which will remove the last digit.

Also, you already calculated the last digit and stored the result in `outcome`.  You might as well use it:

```
arr[outcome]+=1;
```

Then, when you get to the loop to print the array, in the condition, always use `<` an array length to stop after processing the last index `length - 1`.  This will prevent the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that is waiting to show up.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
```